# Which online enquiry should I use to apply for work experience at a law firm?

Tags: work-experience, legal

I'm in year 10 and applying for work experience. On a law firm's website that I want to apply to, they provide a phone number and two different enquiry forms to contact them (no email).

The first enquiry form is for legal issues and has these select buttons with these options:

> I've been injured...
>
> > In the workplace
> > In a road accident
> > etc
>
> Or
>
> I need help with...
>
> > A class action
> > more options...
> > Something else

The only text box that allows me to provide more details about why I am contacting them is labelled 'Legal issue details'.

The other enquiry form is for marketing enquiries but it has a field 'Reason for contacting us' which has an option 'Job/Career Related', as well as a field labelled 'Details' and an option to upload a file.

I think I should apply to the first form, but my mother says otherwise.

Which one should I apply to (or should I just call them)?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's not obvious you should be using this form? *"The other enquiry form is for marketing enquiries but it has a field 'Reason for contacting us' which has an option 'Job/Career Related', as well as a field labelled 'Details' and an option to upload a file."*

Comment: Usually if they do not have a section on their website then they do not accept students for work experience, at least that's how it is in UK.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I'm sure lots of companies might not have ever considered taking on work experience students before they are approached for the first time

Comment: @HorusKol law is slightly different in that department as this is an entryway to further experience/practice which is needed for accreditation. So when they offer such service, there is almost always structure around the intake, etc, due to volume of applicants.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul given the OPs mention of year 10 - this is a 1 or 2 week "work experience" that 15-year olds undertake, not a serious internship for accreditation.

Comment: Don't just call them. Dress nicely and go drop off your resume in person (during off-peak hours). If you're lucky, you'll get interviewed on the spot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be best if you phoned the lawyer's office, rather than try and jam your enquiry into legal enquiry form.

You are likely only going to be able to talk to the receptionist, but they will at least be able to tell if they accept high school students for work experience, and how to make arrangements if they do (this may include having you complete the second form with the "Job/Career Related" option).

Ideally, your school should have a list of businesses that are open to having work experience students, so you should check with your school careers officer, or whichever teacher is responsible for that.

Failing that, you could try and find out if your parents know anyone who could take you on.

Answer (score 1):

Get on the phone, or turn up at their office with your resume.

Why? Because if you apply via a webform, they don't know if they are the only company you've approached, or if you've sent out 250 applications. By making a more personal approach, they can see that you're serious about the application, that you've got a little get-up-and-go, and that you know how to present yourself. It will also set you apart from any other applicants who just use the web form.

It may work, it may not - but just the actions of ringing or turning up will put you in good stead for future applications.